# after installing PHP gd library: when trying to run any PHP parsed page, a save dialog appears

Tags: php, gd, lamp

I've tried to install `GD` library on PHP5:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

Next,

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After that, when trying to run any PHP parsed page, a save dialog appears.

**You can see screenshot:**

I've tried to run `phpinfo.php` page, but same issue:

[image]

**P.S :**

```
$ php -i | grep -i --color gd
```

gd Output test results:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in Unknown on line 0
gd
GD Support => enabled
GD Version => 2.1.0-alpha
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 0 => 0
GDMSESSION => ubuntu
_SERVER["GDMSESSION"] => ubuntu
```

I'm using LAMP server on Linux/Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Apache isn't configured to run PHP

Comment: @HamedKamrava See my answer below.

Comment: Are there any errors showing in the apache2 log files?

Comment: @middaparka Clearly PHP is installed, and simply Apache doesn't have a link to PHP yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in a server deployment not too long ago.

My issue was solved by executing the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Post in the comments below if it doesn't work. Also, reboot your computer after executing this command (so all of the services are restarted), to make things simple.

Comment: I did it. Now try to `localhost` and appears this : `It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.`

Comment: @HamedKamrava Try your PHP script again. ;)

Comment: @HamedKamrava Check to make sure that the directory exists in `/var/www`

Comment: `info.php` is exist in `/var/www`. And i tried `http://localhost/info.php` but get me `403 - Forbidden`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34792/discussion-between-networknerd-and-hamed-kamrava)

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same problem as Hamed. I had to add GD library required by the new project. So far apache2 and PHP5.4 were working together without any problems for months on my machine.

During the installation the script was asking to replace the php.ini and I guess that this was the source of the problem.

So after installing GD, Apache didn't understand PHP anymore so I've reinstalled libapace2-mod-php5 and I had again the similar problems. All my virtual sites have gone returning only standard apache message.

The reason for this is that new version of apache is looking for *.conf files in sites-available folder so you need to rename or copy old vhost file to one with that extension, so e.g.

First go the virtual hosts folder

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

Then copy or rename (actually move) existing vhost file. The owner of this file is root so everything must go through the sudo command

```
$ sudo mv myvhost myvhost.conf
```

Enable the new vhost file

```
$ sudo a2ensite myvhost.conf
```

And finally restart Apache

```
$ sudo apachectl graceful
```

And everything is back to normal, I hope this will help someone.

Comment: on Ubuntu 14.04 after installing php5-gd ... `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libapache2-mod-php5` solved the problem for me

Comment: Thank you @WonderLand  that was the missing bit for me too